# How do I ensure the shell doesn't set ROS Melodic env variables anymore? (Linux)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to source `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` from my `.profile`; every console I open is a login console, anyway. As a first step in installing additional versions of ROS on the same PC, I wanted my environment not to source that `setup.bash` anymore.

I removed the related line from the `.profile`, and, to my amazement, every console I open still has all the ROS Melodic environment variables set. Not only that, but also two of my catkin workspaces are listed in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

The same happens if I open a non-login shell (which ignores the `.profile`).

I have checked the `.bashrc`, and there is nothing sourcing a `setup.bash` in there.

How can I make sure that ROS Melodic env variables are not set at logon? What else should I check, to find where they are currently being set?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and the bash shell. Here the currently set variables:

```
~> printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/fanta/workspace/hrwros_ws/src:/home/fanta/workspace/hrwros_ws_cpp/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/fanta/workspace/hrwros_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

UPDATE: logging out and in again didn't make a difference, but rebooting resolved the issue:

```
~> printenv | grep ROS
~>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342831/how-do-i-ensure-the-shell-doesn%27t-set-ros-melodic-env-variables-anymore?-(linux)/) by [fgfanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/50212/fgfanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-29**:
Are you sure you don't have any file that might be sourcing your workspaces/ros ?
I also had something similar (having some ROS env variables set only) just to find out I forgot something in a `.bash_export` or even a script that was called in the bashrc.

You could try to go to your `$HOME` repository and run `grep -r "source .*setup.bash"`. That may take some time but it might help you find where it's called (if it actually is).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-29**:
You could run a `grep -i melodic -r $HOME` and see what turns up. Note that this will search through *all* files in your home directory, which may not be what you want.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-30**:
Please post your last edit (update) as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Logging out and in again didn't make a difference, but rebooting resolved the issue:

```
~> printenv | grep ROS
~>
```

---

Originally posted by [fgfanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/50212/fgfanta/) with karma: 13 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0